# How to stop a limit a keystroke on a JavaFX textbox

Tags: java, javafx

Like the title says, I am trying to limit the a Javafx textfield to 30 characters. I don't want to create my own textfield, because then, you cannot use it in the scene builder. So far I call the following function using the `OnKeyPressed`

```
@FXML public void limitKeys(KeyEvent e){
  if(e.getSource().equals(this.propertySerialNum)){
      if(this.propertySerialNum.getLength() > 30){
          switch(e.getCode()){
              case BACK_SPACE:
                  break;
              default:
                  e.consume();
                  break;
          }
      }
  }
}
```

So I am trying to only consume the keyevent once the length gets over 30 characters. But the user can use the backspace all the time. But currently it consumes the event but still displays the text. I don't know what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own `TextField` and use it in the `SceneBuilder`.

A good example is explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15188135/995548).

Generally, binding yourself on the `OnKeyPressed` event won't always prevent the max length on the field (Pasting content inside the `TextField`). There's a lot of good example described in the post I linked.

Mainly, you'll want to create a `TextField` that overrides the following method.

```
class LimitedTextField extends TextField {

    private final int limit;

    public LimitedTextField(int limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    @Override
    public void replaceText(int start, int end, String text) {
        super.replaceText(start, end, text);
        verify();
    }

    @Override
    public void replaceSelection(String text) {
        super.replaceSelection(text);
        verify();
    }

    private void verify() {
        if (getText().length() > limit) {
            setText(getText().substring(0, limit));
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: How do i resolve the missing types in scene builder?