# JavaFX TextField - Allow only one letter to be typed

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, textfield

I'm trying to make a Sudoku game in JavaFX but I can't figure out how to only allow one letter to be entered. Would the answer to this to be to call the textfield and do:

```java
myTextField.setOnKeyPressed(e ->
{
    if (!myTextField.getText().length().isEmpty())
    {
        // Somehow reject the key press?
    }
}
```

The above way won't work with copy pasting... or tons of other things, etc. Using key press listeners like this seems like an AWFUL idea. There must be something better? Is there a property of text fields to allow only certain characters to be inputted, or only allow certain number of characters to be inputted?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this Q/A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159988/javafx-2-2-textfield-maxlength

Comment: Note that using a listener for key presses will fail if the user uses the mouse and context menu for copy-and-paste. The accepted answer in the linked question has flaws too; the other answers will work but are outdated as JavaFX 8 has an API specifically for this use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`TextFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) to do this. The `TextFormatter` can modify the changes that are made to the text in the text field if it has a filter associated with it. The filter is a function that takes a `TextFormatter.Change` object and returns an object of the same type. It can return `null` to veto the change entirely, or modify it.

So you can do

```
TextField textField = new TextField();
textField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>((Change change) -> {
    String newText = change.getControlNewText();
    if (newText.length() > 1) {
        return null ;
    } else {
        return change ;
    }
});
```

Note though that the `TextFormatter` can also be used to convert the text to a value of any type you like. In your case, it would make sense to convert the text to an `Integer`, and also to only allow integer input. As a final addition to the user experience, you can modify the change so that if the user types a digit, it replaces the current content (instead of ignoring it if there are too many characters). The whole thing would look like this:

```
    TextField textField = new TextField();

    // converter that converts text to Integers, and vice-versa:
    StringConverter<Integer> stringConverter = new StringConverter<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public String toString(Integer object) {
            if (object == null || object.intValue() == 0) {
                return "";
            }
            return object.toString() ;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer fromString(String string) {
            if (string == null || string.isEmpty()) {
                return 0 ;
            }
            return Integer.parseInt(string);
        }
        
    };
    
    // filter only allows digits, and ensures only one digit the text field:
    UnaryOperator<Change> textFilter = c -> {
    
        // if text is a single digit, replace current text with it:            
        if (c.getText().matches("[1-9]")) {
            c.setRange(0, textField.getText().length());
            return c ;
        } else 
        // if not adding any text (delete or selection change), accept as is    
        if (c.getText().isEmpty()) {
            return c ;
        }
        // otherwise veto change
        return null ;
    };
    
    TextFormatter<Integer> formatter = new TextFormatter<Integer>(stringConverter, 0, textFilter);
    
    formatter.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        // whatever you need to do here when the actual value changes:
        int old = oldValue.intValue();
        int updated = newValue.intValue();
        System.out.println("Value changed from " + old + " to " + updated);
    });
    
    textField.setTextFormatter(formatter);
```

Comment: Wow, it does work very well. I figured there would be way to do it that wasn't a listener. Thanks!