# How i can do textField accepts only character "N or E" in Java?

Tags: java, validation, javafx, textfield

How i can do textField accepts only letter "N or E" in Java? doesn't accept number and another characters.

```
        textField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue.length() > 1) textField.setText(oldValue);
            if (newValue.matches("[^\\d]")) return;
            textField.setText(newValue.replaceAll("\\d*", ""));
        });
```

i tryed this, this worked for maxValue. But i am need textField accept only "N" and "E" characters.
So how i can do this?

Comment: Do you mean the single letter `N` or the single letter `E`? Or any combination of them, e.g. `NE`, `NNNNN`, `EEEEEE`, `ENEN`?

Comment: Use a `TextFormatter`. Don't use a listener to modify the change. See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34407694/javafx-textfield-allow-only-one-letter-to-be-typed answers your question.

Comment: @guninvalid no i mean only get single letter N or E .

Comment: Note also that if the user is required to choose between just two options, a `TextField` might not be the best user experience. Consider radio buttons, a check box, or a combo box instead.

Comment: @James_D this is not solution for my task. this is need use only in textField

Comment: What is your task? Why would it need to work that way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `TextFormatter`. You can modify or veto the proposed change to the text. This version:

- Only accepts changes where the text typed (or pasted) is "N" or "E" (either upper or lower case)
- Makes the text upper case
- Changes the proposed change so that it replaces existing text, instead of adding to it
- Allows for deleting the current text

Your exact requirements may differ slightly. See the [Javadocs for `TextFormatter.Change`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.Change.html) for more details.

```
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class NorETextField extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> filter = c -> {
            if (c.getText().matches("[NnEe]")) {
                c.setText(c.getText().toUpperCase());
                c.setRange(0, textField.getText().length());
                return c ;
            } else if (c.getText().isEmpty()) {
                return c ;
            }
            return null ;
        };
        textField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>(filter));
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(textField);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you, this is worked very well. <3

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. This accept only character N

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("N");
        UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> filter = c -> {
            if (pattern.matcher(c.getControlNewText()).matches()) {
                return c ;
            } else {
                return null ;
            }
        };
        TextFormatter<String> formatter = new TextFormatter<>(filter);
        textField.setTextFormatter(formatter);
```